# Can I use Doctrine transaction together with mysql PDO statements?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, doctrine-orm

From below code I expect that $query1 will be undone after Exception is 
thrown. But it's not.

```
try {
    $this->em->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
    PDO::exec($query1 = 'INSERT INTO foo...')
    throw new Exception();
    PDO::exec($query2 = 'INSERT INTO bar...')
    $this->em->flush();
    $this->em->getConnection()->commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $this->em->getConnection()->rollBack();
    throw $e;
}
```

Comment: whats is `$query1` `$query2`.? Post all relevant code..

Comment: INSERT INTO something like.